# Need help with displaying chars starting from line1 position 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms

I am using an HP RS232 pole display with setting as listed below. Also the documentation is provided in this link: http://www.camax.it/manuali/Manuale%20LD220%20VFD.pdf

- Char type:     USA/Europe (default)
- Command mode:  EPSON (default)
- Baud rate:     9600, n , 8, 1 (default)
- Passthru        None (Default)

### Here's the code

```
using System.IO.Ports;

private SerialPort port;
port = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.Handshake = Handshake.None;

Port.WriteLine("Welocome to something something");
```

It has 2 lines consisting of 20 characters each with a total of 40 characters. I have no control how and where the characters get displayed. I would like it to always begin on line 1 position 1 but as I said earlier how would I be able to do that. The same program if I run again and again it moves a character to the left. I have set it to accept ASCII char set and so I am able to type as is visble in the Writeline message. But I could set it as Hex if needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to *somehow* communicate to the printer's device driver library to have it *always begin on line 1 position 1*;

Try [epsonexpert.com](http://epsonexpert.com) for EPSON device driver library for .NET. Also [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/posfordotnet/thread/ca51f535-ad26-4557-9184-6c1f6ff6223d) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187465/drive-a-pos-printer-via-usb-in-c/187504#187504) discussion might help.

Comment: I do not have any devices attached to my PC except the pole display